# Decoding signed CAN bytes in C

Tags: c, hex, endianness, can-bus

I've been trying to write a function to decode CAN bytes in C, taking into account endianness of values coming in and endianness of system. Now, it works fine for unsigned values, but sucks for signed ones.

I have a feeling I have deeply misunderstood how signed representation works in C - I assumed the MSB was the sign flag for signed data (ie last byte of Little Endian, first byte of Big Endian). Could anybody take a look at my function below and let me know what I've done wrong?

```
/**
 * @brief can_interact_decode - converts array of length x containing hex bytes into a uint64
 * @param[in] const uint8_t* - const array of hex bytes
 * @param[in] const size_t - length of hex bytes array
 * @param[in] const enum can_interact_signedness - whether the bytes are storing a signed value or not. SIGNED_VAL indicates signed, UNSIGNED_VAL indicates unsigned
 * @param[in] const enum can_interact_endianness - endianess. LITTLE_ENDIAN_VAL is little, BIG_ENDIAN_VAL is big
 * @return[out] uint64_t - interpreted value as unsigned int from hex bytes, taking other params into account
 */
uint64_t can_interact_decode(const uint8_t *payload, const size_t data_len, const enum can_interact_signedness is_signed, const enum can_interact_endianness byte_order)
{
    uint64_t result; /* [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] */
    uint8_t* blocks; /* array of 8 */
    result = 0;
    blocks = (uint8_t*)(&result);

    if(byte_order == LITTLE_ENDIAN_VAL) {
        memcpy(blocks, payload, (is_signed ? data_len - 1 : data_len));
        blocks[7] = is_signed ? payload[data_len - 1] : blocks[7];
        result = le64toh(result); /* little endian->host byte order */
    } else if(byte_order == BIG_ENDIAN_VAL) {
        memcpy(blocks + (8 - data_len) + (is_signed ? 1 : 0), (is_signed ? payload + 1 : payload), (is_signed ? data_len - 1 : data_len));
        blocks[0] = is_signed ? payload[0] : blocks[0];
        result = be64toh(result); /* big endian->host byte order */
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: "last byte of Little Endian, first byte of Big Endian" --> The sign _bit_, not _byte_, is part of those bytes.

Comment: Is `data_len` ever more that 8? or less than 1?

Comment: no it isn't. I will add ifs etc. checking this kind of stuff. Writing a library so for other functionality I have actually got all that stuff written in there, but was just trying to focus on base functionality at this point @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: ah. i see my error. if you'd be so kind, how would one extract the most significant *bit* from a byte? im guessing something to do with << or >> operators? @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Do you mean `(int8_t) payload[data_len - 1] < 0`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm sorry, which line do you think you're offering a correction to?

Comment: You can't swap endianess with `memcpy`. You need to mask out every byte then bitwise OR them together in the new type. It doesn't matter if the data is signed or unsigned, as long as you do the bitwise arithmetic on unsigned types. As for signed _bytes_ endianess does not apply at all.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could focus on solving the actual problem, as in post the format of your CAN frame and explain how you wish to store that data in your program (running on little endian CPU?).

Comment: @Lundin im writing stuff to make working with CAN easier, as a bit of a pet project. I've worked with C before with some controller code, drivers, basic shell-interpreters and encrypted command-line communication channel before but I'd like to get more familiar with literal lower level operations. As for CAN, i've worked with it before but just wanted to make my life easier by creating generic functions rather than dumping memory etc.

Comment: How can general CAN handling code know things about the payload? That's the application tier's duty. If you get 8 bytes of data, well it could be a `uint64_t`, 2x`uint32_t`, 4x`uint16_t` or 8 raw bytes (where endianess does not apply). Or any combination of the mentioned. Or floating point even. In every single situation, you have to decode that frame differently. Therefore endianess must be handled by the application tier which knows the nature of the specific frame with a certain identifier.

Comment: I'm aware. Hence you can specify the length of data as well as it's starting point, and then the endian-ness of the data sent. Functions auto detect endian of host, number of bytes that needs to be read from a starting point, and what type was being transmitted, and then it assembles it. All this function does is use all those bits of info to format it automatically, but relies on user to provide that info.

Comment: if you want to see how its meant to work, https://github.com/daleksla/can_interact

Comment: Finally got everything working so I've made a pre-release: https://github.com/daleksla/can_interact/tree/v0.1   . Capable of setting up CAN connection, filtering ids, decoding and encoding signed, unsigned and floating point data, and then sending them. Hope the examples/ section illustrates a bit more of its usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

**Sign extending woes**

OP appears to want to sign extend the sign *bit* into other *bytes*.

```
if(byte_order == LITTLE_ENDIAN_VAL) {
    //memcpy(blocks, payload, (is_signed ? data_len - 1 : data_len));
    //blocks[7] = is_signed ? payload[data_len - 1] : blocks[7];
    memcpy(blocks, payload, data_len);
    if (is_signed && ((const int8_t*)payload)[data_len - 1] < 0) {
      memset(blocks + data_len, 0xFF, 8 - data_len);
    }  
    result = le64toh(result); /* little endian->host byte order */
```

I will leave similar changes in `else if(byte_order == BIG_ENDIAN_VAL)` block for OP to do.

Comment: Apart from the uninitialised data comment (as I do 2 lines below), this all seems wonderful and I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @SalihMSA Tip: rather than `var_type var; /* lines later */ var = 0;`, consider `var_type var = 0;`.  It is clearer code.

Comment: tried doing this for big endian:

Comment: if (is_signed && payload[0] < 0) {
   memset(blocks, 0xFF, 8 - data_len);
  }
  result = be64toh(result); /* big endian->host byte order */

Comment: @SalihMSA `payload[0] < 0` is always false as `payload[0]` is _unsigned_.  This hints you are not compiling with all warnings enabled.  Save time.  Enable them all.

Comment: I am compiling with -Wall, but forgot -Wextra (which I usually have enabled). Dunce move, thanks

Comment: At a minimum, I use _-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion_.

Comment: oh, i forgot the cast was needed otherwise itd be a uint8_t. silly me

Comment: For BE, perhaps `memcpy(blocks + (8 - data_len), payload), data_len); if (is_signed && ((const int8_t*)payload)[0] < 0) {  memset(blocks, 0xFF, 8 - data_len);`?

Comment: Careful with recommending `-Wconversion` to beginners though, it comes with lots of false positives.

Comment: @Lundin Disagree that -Wconversion comes with lots of false positives.  Sure the issues are often benign, but not _false_.

Comment: It's good practice to regard warnings as things that need fixed, and it's very good practice to accept zero warnings in release build. With `-Wconversion` you'll achieve neither of those criteria, because it will whine about a lot of things that don't need fixing.

Comment: Also it's fairly broken. It warns for `int x = 1u + myint;` but doesn't warn for `int x = 1 ? 1u : myint;`. It's dangerous to rely on compiler features that only work in very specific situations.